# enable/ disable button based on value entered in text box angular 4 - initial load not working

Tags: angular

I need to enable / disable the below button and I have the below code. It works fine only from second time onwards. Initially when I land on the page, the button should be disabled because I dont have a value in the input box. If i enter something inside the text box and delete it , the button gets disabled. How do I disable the button for the first when I land on the page in angular 4

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputValue"  placeholder="johndoe@company.com" formControlName="inputValue">
 <button type="button" id="verifyBtn" [disabled]="inputValue === ''" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" (click)="verify()">Verify</button>
```

Comment: Sidenote... do not use formcontrol and ngmodel together. It will be deprecated soon anyway. And from v6, this would also give you a warning.

Comment: Ahh okay.. SO how do i achieve this without ngModel

Comment: You would set the initial value for the formcontrol instead of ngModel. But in this case you wouldn't want an intial value :) Pleae show the component code.

Comment: @AJT_82 I have lots of code in component file. Which part of component code you want to see?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set input like this:

```
[disabled]="!inputValue"
```

Because the `inputValue` value is not set at the beginning, which is undefined, so when you check `inputValue === ''` it will be false

[Update based on comment]
If you use `[(ngModel)]`, which is bi-directional, you need to be careful about the data input from view to controller, and output from controller to view. In many times, It is a bad design.

Because you use `fromControlName`, which is reactiveForm, you should just use reactiveForm and subscription to handle input value. You can check the [post](https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-forms-reactive)

Comment: Excellent solution!1

Comment: I think there is a problem with because of both ngModel and formControlName . With ngModel , I am getting the value of inputValue field as undefined in ts file. (this.personalDtlsForm.value.inputValue !== ''")   If i remove that ngModel , the value is getting passed as "" . As a result of this I had to remove the ngModel code. Is there any way to achieve this without using ngModel ?

Comment: But where is the solution ? How do i disable the button without using ngModel and with formControlName

Comment: When using reactive forms, you can use the form validation, and using the validation result to control whether to disable or show error.

Comment: That is for form validation . I was asking to disable a single button that is present inside the form

Answer (score 2):

Based on you updated question you want to disable button control when you land on page , to do that you should create your form control like as below

```
this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
  inputValue : ['', Validators.required ],
});
```

if you do as above then you control will enter in invalidate state first time itself. in your button html you should do this

```
<form [formGroup]="heroForm">
    <button
     type="button"
     id="verifyBtn"
     formControlName="inputValue"
     [disabled]="heroForm.get('inputValue').invlaid"
     class="btn btn-primary btn-large"
     (click)="verify()">Verify</button>
  </form>
```

---

can you try like this , so code below checks inputvalue is there or not and if inputvalue is there check that its has value or not

```
[disabled]="!inputValue || (inputValue && inputValue.length < 1)"
```

Comment: Great solution !!

Comment: I am facing the issue with this. I have mentioned by comment in the above answer

Comment: @Nancy - i dont see comment on my answer ...where you commented

Comment: I think there is a problem with because of both ngModel and formControlName . With ngModel , I am getting the value of inputValue field as undefined in ts file. (this.personalDtlsForm.value.inputValue !== ''") If i remove that ngModel , the value is getting passed as "" . As a result of this I had to remove the ngModel code. Is there any way to achieve this without using ngModel ?

Comment: @Nancy - you cannot use both Template drive from approch and Rective form approach, you have to use one of them ...if you can update question i can add my answer according to it ....

Comment: I have updated my question to use reactive forms approach. Could you pls provide an answer to it

Comment: @Nancy - updated my answer based on your input have look

Comment: I am getting error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined . seems like invalid is supported only for forms and not for fields. Well , I am not sure though

Comment: @Nancy - please check update, and as suggested please go through reactive form approach , in angular , link : https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms